# Accented characters appearing in rxvt

Tags: rxvt, minix

I have a quite specific question which I've spent hours trying to solve, but have finally decided it is time to ask for help.

I'm currently doing some work which requires me to ssh from a debian machine into a ubuntu box and run a qemu instance running minix.
i.e `debian --ssh--> ubuntu --qemu--> minix`.

Minix uses `f1` - `f12` and `alt+f1` keys quite extensively. I find that if I use gnome terminal it tends to grab the alt and function keys. I've had great success with xterm in that it allows me to use the function keys without issue. However, it still doesn't accept the alt key.

So I downloaded rxvt and it seems to allow me to do everything I require (alt + f1/f2/f3/etc works fine). However after I finish using the alt key, the output on the terminal is accented characters. I've found that I can reset the keys back to normal by pressing `ctrl + menu key` or `alt + menu key`
If I enter the alphabet after using an alt combination this is what it looks like:
[image: example of alphabet]
I realize that this might not be the easiest problem to diagnose, but if anyone could suggest so much as a starting point that could put me on the right track I'd appreciate it.